# Having Trouble with Innerjoins

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I am having trouble getting this query to work.  The goal is to get the `strategy_id` between the dates specified

```
(MM_DATE BETWEEN '10-mar-2014' AND '13-mar-2014')
```

that havent yet expired

```
(AND b.END_DATE > '03-apr-2014') and have a Media_cost > 0.
```

The `END_DATE` and `MM_DATE` are in separate tables, and the `Strategy_ID = ID` is the common thread.

```
SELECT c.MM_DATE
       ,c.STRATEGY_ID
       ,c.EXCH_ID
       ,c.CREATIVE_ID
       ,c.MEDIA_COST
       ,b.END_DATE
    FROM T1_RPT_PERFORMANCE c
    INNER JOIN T1_META_STRATEGY b
        ON c.STRATEGY_ID = b."ID"
    WHERE c.MM_DATE BETWEEN '10-mar-2014' AND '13-mar-2014'
        AND c.EXCH_ID = 18,
        AND c.MEDIA_COST > 0,
        AND b.END_DATE > '03-apr-2014'
    GROUP BY c.STRATEGY_ID;
```

Error message:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem in more detail? Any error messages?

Comment: I keep getting this error message ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Answer (score 4):

Remove the commas within your where clause.

Explicitly  after `c.EXCH_ID=18 and c.MEDIA_COST > 0`.